# Can same meta data tables be used for multiple spring batches

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

Example :
I have two different batches
batch-a , batch-b running on azure connecting to onprem db.
batch-a is deployed first and creates a meta data table.
lets say batch-b is deployed after few months .

Can it use the same meta tables that was created and used by batch-a?

Answer (score 0):

If `batch-a` and `batch-b` is different Jobs, then you can use the same Spring Batch Metadata tables, it depends if `batch-a` and `batch-b` is connecting to same DB then yes Spring Batch Framework will automatically take care of it.

See my article here: https://prateek-ashtikar512.medium.com/spring-batch-metadata-in-different-schema-c18813a0448a

Comment: (I think the linked article is written by you - I have made an edit to clarify that. Please let me know if I am mistaken.)

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your answer...
Basically batch-a and batch-b are completely different artifacts(code base)... Are you also saying the same ? 
I am more concerned how spring takes care of parallel execution. What if they  are running at the same time and try to update the metadata at the same time. 
Do we need to take care of locking for inserts etc?